# Effect of log transformation on AICc

Tags: r, multiple-regression, data-transformation, linear-model, model-selection

I have been re-running some multiple linear regression models (using R package `nlme`) that I had initially log-transformed in R due to violation of the assumption of normality of residuals based on `shapiro.test()`, but upon visual inspection of the residual plots, the plots do not appear that bad. However, I've noticed that the best model using the untransformed dependent variable based on the lowest AICc is slightly different than the best model based on the log-transformed dependent variable. The difference is minor with one extra parameter that is not significant(eg. A+B+C×D vs. A+C×D), and all significant variables are the same in both models, but I don't understand why log transforming would lead to different best models based on AICc selection criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't transforming lead to different best models?  Consider an example where we are fitting a linear model with two continuous predictors, where the true relationship is something like:

$$
Y = \exp(\beta_1 X_1) \times(\beta_2 X_2 + \epsilon_2)
$$

If we fit on the original scale, we have $Y \propto \beta_2 X_2$, so a linear model is likely to fit reasonably well to $X_2$.

If we fit on the logged scale, we have $\log(Y) = C + \beta_1 X_1$, so a linear model is likely to fit reasonably well to $X_1$.

None of this is exact (the error terms will be a bit weird), but it might give you the idea that different predictors can do a good job predicting on different scales ...

---

Other thoughts:

- Normality is the *least* important of the linear model assumptions (independence, linearity, homoscedasticity, absence of outliers ...)  How do the rest of your model diagnostics look?
- Is there one scale or other (linear/original vs. logged) that is more natural or theoretically justified for your particular problem?